# Use the using directive on a private nested class

Tags: c++, class-visibility

I have been developing a library for a while and now that I think it's ready, I am trying to follow the [pimpl principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) in order to hide implementation details.

```
// File Class.h
class Class {
public:
  Class();

private:
    class ClassImpl;
    ClassImpl* rep;
};

// File Class.cpp
#include "Class.h"
#include "ClassImpl.h"
Class::Class() {
    rep = new ClassImpl();
}
```

The implementation class is defined in another file as follow

```
// File ClassImpl.h
#include "Class.h"
class Class::ClassImpl {
public:
  ClassImpl();
};
```

And its implementation:

```
// File ClassImpl.cpp
#include "ClassImpl.h"
#include <iostream>

using C = Class::ClassImpl; // error: 'class Class::ClassImpl' is private
C::ClassImpl() {
  std::cout << "Implementation constructor";
}
```

Main function:

```
// File main.cpp
#include "Class.h"
int main() {
    Class c;
    return 0;
}
```

Doing this, the compiler says `error: 'class Class::ClassImpl' is private` on the using line in `ClassImpl.cpp`. If I remove it and use `Class::ClassImpl` instead, everything works fine.

Is there a way to use `using`on the private nested class `ClassImpl` ?

Comment: Does the example at the end of the page, that you refer to, do the same thing as you? Do they also try to use `using` and the `impl` of the `widget` class in the `main()` function? No.

Comment: @JoeyMallone no because they define the function inside the class declaration. It seems a good idea in the example page but because my implementation is hundred-of-line-long, then it is not adequate to me

Comment: try this `ClassImpl::ClassImpl() {` for the constructor and leave `using`.

Comment: I have nothing to back up this claim (hence only as a comment), but no, it is not possible. You are trying to create an [alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). Imagine if you could create an alias to any private symbol. That would break the entire purpose of access modifiers, wouldn't it? Anyhow, although I hate the precompiler, you can achieve the same code reduction by simply defining a constant: `#define C Class::ClassImpl`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use usingon the private nested class ClassImpl ?

Yes. Declare `ClassImpl` with public access in `Class`:

```
class Class {
public:
    Class();
    class ClassImpl;

private:
    ClassImpl* rep; // should be reference, see note.
};

// ...

using C = Class::ClassImpl;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dba79b26148f0da)

You can also make `ClassImpl` not a nested class.

Note: you might prefer having `Class::rep` to be a reference rather than a (naked) pointer. There is no reason for a valid `Class` instance not to have an implementation object (a null pointer).

Comment: The naked pointer was just for the example, I use smart pointers actually

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use `using` on the private nested class `ClassImpl`?

The short answer is "no".

Longer answer follows.

What you're trying to do is a `using` declaration, not a `using` directive.

Your using declaration

> ```
> using C = Class::ClassImpl;
> ```

is at file scope, so the name `Class::ClassImpl` cannot be used directly as a name in that scope.

The first relevant section of the standard (C++17) is Section 10.3.3 "The `using` declaration", for which para 19 states "A synonym created by a *using-declaration* has the usual accessibility for a *member-declaration*".

To find what is meant by "usual accessibility", refer to Section 14 "Member Access Control", which states that "`private` names can only be used by members and friends of the class in which it is declared".  The usage of "names" here is quite specific - anything with a name that is `private` to a class (member declarations, type declarations, etc) are treated the same way.

If you want to have a `using` declaration at file scope, as per your example;

> ```
> using C = Class::ClassImpl;
> ```

then `ClassImpl` needs to be a `public` name (of a nested class) of `Class`.   `private` and `protected` names of a class cannot be accessed at file scope.